# Execute shell commands ubuntu in Python

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, programming

I'm currently studying Automation and Python programming. I just want to know how I would go about executing a Linux command in Python. The commands I want to execute are:

```
install = os.system("mysql_secure_installation")
Enter current password for root (Enter for None):
```

how to enter the script after
`Enter current password for root (Enter for None):`

if i use `install = os.system` is can't process

Comment: Run `mysql_secure_installation` with arguments to not be prompted.

Comment: Would pexpect help? Example: https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/examples/ftp.py